# Flatten JSON into Specific Format

Tags: java, json

I'd like to use Java to take in a JSON body, iterate through the records, and output every other record into a new JSON array. Each set of two records will be its own array, and I only need to take the first one in each respective array. I'll also be providing the column names in the original request that need to be added to the subsequent flattened object. For example, let's say I have the following JSON request body:

```
{
  "records": [
    [
        [
            "0DFC29E2-700E-4CC1-931E-B61DF4954B6B",
            "John Doe",
            "Teacher",
            "China"
        ],
        [
            "B5B9186E-CE65-4911-8516-C510D3CC3ACE",
            "Jane Doe",
            "Doctor",
            "London"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "20C4DD07-4E96-47F8-A1E1-B20B4C48120C",
            "Jim Doe",
            "Lawyer",
            "Canada"
        ],
        [
            "76718CB1-238F-418E-BD14-5E2867FF3FB4",
            "Jack Doe",
            "Chef",
            "Mexico"
        ]
     ]
   ],
    "columns": [
     "ID",
     "Name",
     "Occupation",
     "Location"
   ]
}
```

I'd then like this request body flattened to the following:

```
[{
  "ID": "0DFC29E2-700E-4CC1-931E-B61DF4954B6B",
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Occupation": "Teacher",
  "Location": "China"
},
{
  "ID": "20C4DD07-4E96-47F8-A1E1-B20B4C48120C",
  "Name": "Jim Doe",
  "Occupation": "Lawyer",
  "Location": "Canada"
}]
```

I'd like this code to be pretty dynamic, so it doesn't explicitly reference the column names in code. That way I can pass up other column names in the future if I have a different JSON body structure, and it will work accordingly. I'll always be passing up the data with a title of "records" so that's okay to hardcode. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert source JSON into collection of maps. Each map will be contain property names and property values. After that, you can easily serialize it to expected format. In below example I use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library, but I think you should be able to use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library too.

At first, we should define `SourceEntity` class which define all properties for input JSON.

```
class SourceEntity {

    private String[][][] records;
    private String[] columns;

    public String[][][] getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(String[][][] records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    public String[] getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(String[] columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }
}
```

After that, we should write converter, which can parse input JSON, convert arrays into collection of maps and serialize it to target JSON.

```
class JsonConverter {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();

    public String convert(File sourceJsonFile) throws Exception {
        SourceEntity sourceEntity = parseSourceEntity(sourceJsonFile);
        List<Map<String, String>> result = convertToTargetPropertiesMap(sourceEntity);

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result);
    }

    private SourceEntity parseSourceEntity(File sourceJsonFile)
            throws Exception {
        JsonParser parser = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(sourceJsonFile);
        return objectMapper.readValue(parser, SourceEntity.class);
    }

    private List<Map<String, String>> convertToTargetPropertiesMap(
            SourceEntity entity) {
        List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        for (String[][] pairs : entity.getRecords()) {
            list.add(createPropertyMap(entity.getColumns(), pairs[0]));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private Map<String, String> createPropertyMap(String[] names,
            String[] values) {
        Map<String, String> propertyMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            propertyMap.put(names[i], values[i]);
        }
        return propertyMap;
    }
}
```

Finally, we should write a little test:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JsonConverter converter = new JsonConverter();
        String result = converter.convert(new File("/tmp/source.json"));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Above program prints this JSON for your example input:

```
[{"ID":"0DFC29E2-700E-4CC1-931E-B61DF4954B6B","Name":"John Doe","Occupation":"Teacher","Location":"China"},{"ID":"20C4DD07-4E96-47F8-A1E1-B20B4C48120C","Name":"Jim Doe","Occupation":"Lawyer","Location":"Canada"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the source JSON into a bunch of Java objects, do the transform on the Java side, and output in the new format.

It would be nice if there were a JSON equivalent to XSLT, but I haven't seen one that's in general use.